# how do i pass js string variable to php without losing newlines and spaces?

Tags: php, javascript, string, variables

i have a javascript variable which contains a string with new lines and spaces e.g "a \n     d" i want to pass this to php without losing any spaces or new lines. currently i am using this:

```
my_window = window.open("", "ChemEdit Molfile", "status=1,width=550,height=350");    
urlString = "/chemedit/b.php?var=" +r;
my_window.location = urlString;
```

where `r` is the string i pass.

but if i do this in php

```
echo $_GET["var"];
```

i just get it on one line with the spaces gone

please help

Comment: Have you tried to escape the r variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the string, you can use `encodeURIcomponent()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try using `encodeURIComponent` function:

```
my_window.location = encodeURIComponent(urlString);
```

Comment: +1 but more like `urlString = "/chemedit/b.php?var=" + encodeURIComponent(r);`

Answer (score 0):

if you're going to pass newline and spaces in an url,
you have to abide by the character rules of url strings,
in which spaces must be represented as '%20' and newlines 
'\n" is '%5Cn'. the answers above will probably do this
automatically, but if you find you ever need to manually
encode or adjust, here is a reference for all special ascii
characters that should be converted for passing through 
an http header request: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp